ReactiveKafkaConsumer template pause/resume on rebalance
I am new to reactive kafka. I am using the reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate to process my messages. I have the pause and resume methods as
public void pauseKafkaRead() {
    kafkaConsumerTemplate.assignment()
        .flatMap(o -> kafkaConsumerTemplate.pause(o))
        .subscribe();
}

public void resumeKafkaRead() {
    kafkaConsumerTemplate.assignment()
        .flatMap(o -> kafkaConsumerTemplate.resume(o))
        .subscribe();
}

public Flux<ReceiverRecord<String, String>> consume() {
    return reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate
        .receiveAutoAck()
        .flatMap(this::processMessage)
        .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
}

I have the Receiveroptions configured for it
ReceiverOptions.create(props)
    .subscription(Collections.singleton("myTopic"));

I want to pause/resume the partitions assigned to my consumer based on a certain condition flag isConsuming. But, I am not sure how to have partitions assigned/revoked during a rebalance to honor this flag setting. How can I implement this
